# Electron app - audio issues

Tags: electron

We are having an electron based WebRTC application, Which has a typical role of routing calls to users. We are facing one issue in that. Application starts properly user is able to converse on calls with 2 way audio I/P and O/P.

But after sometime, electron application stops users audio output.

ex:
( user -> speaks -> caller ) ( works )
( caller -> speaks -> user ) ( fails they cannot hear them )

Note: USER's headphones are proper and working.
We did few calls in CHROME at the same time, it works properly.

After we restart BrowserWindow, did few test calls, we can see 2-way audio. we would like to debug this issue. If you have any ideas how we can debug this issue will be of great help for us.

Electron version: 1.7.x 64bit
Operating system: Mac
Expected behavior

2 way audio should work properly

Actual behavior

only CALLER can hear voice from USER vice versa is failing.

** After restarting BrowserWindow, It works properly on new calls for sometime. **

Can someone help us, how to debug this issue. Any clue on debugging will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does it match the behaviour of the infamous "webrtc osx audio bug" described [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=4799#c133)?

Comment: Thanks @philipp

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=4799

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=160920.   [chrome 63](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEXnbTyygi4&feature=youtu.be&t=10m33s) is landing these fixes by Dec 5, hope to see this integration electron soon

Closing this issue.

Comment: one more thing to note, for us mic audio is working but, user cannot hear audio o/p in speakers or headphones.

But we can hear audio i/p from user side. I assume this is related to it. those threads are huge to dig in :)  going through them.